# Listview Checkbox.IsEnabled bind to Parent Checkbox.IsChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, checkbox

I try to bind the `IsEnabled` Property of a Checkbox to `IsChecked` of another Checkbox in a `Listview`. What is wrong?

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Rulesets}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Rules}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Name="rulesetCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding IsActivated}"></CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=rulesetCheckbox, Path=IsChecked}"  IsChecked="{Binding IsActivated}"></CheckBox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why just don't bind to IsActivated?

Comment: Got binding errors?

Comment: @Jamaxack Because that binding uses a different DataContext?

Comment: No Jamaxack is right, i didn't thought about this. How can i access the parent DataContext in this case?

Comment: Go it! Thanks!  IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.IsActivated}"